# How to use property file value in PageFactory @FindBy annotation?

Tags: java, webdriver

I've recently started using Selenium2 with the Page Object Pattern in 
conjunction with Page Factory. I have the WebElements declared with 
@FindBy Annotations that are initialized by the PageFactory when the 
class is initialized. However I would like to use the @FindBy 
Annotation with a locators.properties file. Unfortunately I don't seem 
to be able to do this as the Annotation is restricted to only allowing 
Constant Expressions. This seems to be a limitation in Java 
Annotations in general but I'm just wondering if anybody has found a 
workaround for this. I would prefer to load the locators from an 
external source but then I would lose the benefits of using 
PageFactory.

public class LoginPage {

```
    protected WebDriver driver; 

    @FindBy(id = "username") 
    private WebElement usernameField; 

    @FindBy(id = "password") 
    private WebElement passwordField; 

    @FindBy(id = "button_login") 
    private WebElement loginButton; 

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) { 
            this.driver = driver; 
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); 
    }
```

}

I would like to implement something similar to this but I can't 
because the Annotation will not allow this:

public class LoginPage {

```
    protected WebDriver driver; 

    Properties locators = new Properties(); 

    @FindBy(id = locators.getProperty("login.usernameField")) 
    private WebElement usernameField; 

    @FindBy(id = locators.getProperty("login.passwordField")) 
    private WebElement passwordField; 

    @FindBy(id = locators.getProperty("login.loginButton")) 
    private WebElement loginButton; 

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) { 
            this.driver = driver; 
            // Load the locators.properties File here 
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); 
    }
```

}

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The values provided to any annotation is computed at compile time & not at run time. However, if your intention is to store locators in property file, then you could use By clause... Here is an example C# code:              public By UserName() { return By.Id(locators.getProperty("login.usernameField")); } and later you could use Driver.FindElement(UserName()).SendKeys("")..

Comment: check this out, you may get some idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981498/selenium-page-object-reuse

Answer (score 0):

You can't at the moment.

You could always write a way to do it and offer it up as a patch that can be applied back into the Selenium codebase :)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible and this link is indeed helpful [Selenium Page Object Reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981498/selenium-page-object-reu)‌​se

I have managed to read locators from config, please take a look
[Selenium Page Object. How to read @FindBy locator from external source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914981/selenium-page-object-how-to-read-findby-locator-from-external-source/39947857#39947857)